# Calculating the fitted values from a gls() object in R

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, autoregressive, generalized-least-squares

I have created a `gls()` object to create a linear model with AR(1) errors. By all indications this model is a good fit for the data and the resulting model appears to stick to the assumptions. However, when I call `$fitted` from the model the fitted values are not very accurate at all, in fact they are all contained in [61,62] when my response has values in [55,68]. I have done some research and I have had conflicting statements about the formula to calculate the fitted values so was wondering if anyone has had the same issue or could help clear up the theory behind calculating the fitted values?
this is my code specifically,

```
gls1 <- gls(Weight ~ ., data = patientdata, correlation = corAR1())
```

Comment: `fitted(gls1)` should return the fitted values. As to why the fitted values are not accurate, you'd need to provide much more details about the data and model.

Comment: I am happy to do so but I was more looking to see what the theoretical form of the fitted values in this case would be as I can then assess if it is right. My main source of confusion is whether they include the previous error term or not, as some online sources have said they do but this doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Is this the exact syntax you used? Do not understand this, what is the id and what is time, given that you want AR1 over "time"?

Comment: Yes this is the syntax I used, the data is sensitive so I cannot share much about it but it is fitting weight against nutritional data, the goal here is to account for the correlation between weight measurements and from PACF and ACF plots the residuals of my linear model exhibit an AR(1) relationship.